# Why I cannot get this string in RStudio?

Tags: r, string

I am trying to read a phylogeny (as text) into R using RStudio. I copied the text and put them in quotes. But now I cannot even assign it to a variable in R.

```r
tree = "(((((((((((((Potentilla_intermedia:0.311566,Potentilla_recta:0.311566):0.802855,Potentilla_pensylvanica:1.114421):0.041676,(Potentilla_gracilis:1.110417,Potentilla_argentea:1.110417):0.04568):8.56704,(((Potentilla_norvegica:0.063773,Potentilla_supina:0.063773):0.051902,Potentilla_hippiana:0.115675):8.590754,Argentina_anserina:8.706429):1.016709):0.602701,Potentilla_bipinnatifida:10.325839):8.923901,(((Potentilla_anglica:1.366781,Potentilla_reptans:1.366781):5.302408,(Potentilla_simplex:0.031597,Potentilla_canadensis:0.031597):6.637592):0.621378,Duchesnea_indica:7.290567):11.959172):1.543066,Potentilla_sterilis:20.792806):11.333216,(((((Fragaria_chiloensis:2.648747,Fragaria_vesca:2.648747):1.022985,Fragaria_virginiana:3.671731):17.684618,(Dasiphora_fruticosa:11.647099,Potentilla_arguta:11.647099):9.709251):0.676268,Drymocallis_arguta:22.032617):0.405466,((Alchemilla_monticola:16.875311,Alchemilla_xanthochlora:16.875311):0.887368,Comarum_palustre:17.762679):4.675404):9.687939):6.026567,((((((((Rosa_setigera:3.378155,Rosa_blanda:3.378155):0.030747,Rosa_carolina:3.408902):0.025377,Rosa_arkansana:3.434279):1.991106,((Rosa_rubiginosa:2.358272,Rosa_spinosissima:2.358272):0.07664,Rosa_multiflora:2.434911):2.990474):0.128884,Rosa_woodsii:5.554269):0.86504,Rosa_acicularis:6.419309):6.730804,(((((Rosa_micrantha:0.188519,Rosa_canina:0.188519):0.012649,Rosa_tomentosa:0.201168):0.03073,Rubus_plicatifolius:0.231898):0.29401,Rosa_palustris:0.525908):2.38304,Rosa_rugosa:2.908948):10.241165):23.677485,((((Agrimonia_pubescens:0.020923,Agrimonia_gryposepala:0.020923):3.336778,Agrimonia_striata:3.357701):1.373162,(Agrimonia_rostellata:1.363567,Agrimonia_parviflora:1.363567):3.367296):20.869366,Sanguisorba_minor:25.600229):11.227369):1.324992):6.47604,((((Geum_laciniatum:1.819705,Geum_canadense:1.819705):3.890036,(Geum_aleppicum:5.612049,Geum_urbanum:5.612049):0.097692):2.792243,((Geum_macrophyllum:2.602326,Geum_triflorum:2.602326):2.49947,Geum_vernum:5.101796):3.400188):2.651319,Geum_rivale:11.153303):33.475326):1.449852,((((((((((((((((((((((Rubus_semisetosus:2.411266,Rubus_frondosus:2.411266):0.563329,Rubus_wisconsinensis:2.974595):0.095095,(Rubus_wheeleri:2.378801,Rubus_fulleri:2.378801):0.690888):0.0356,Rubus_glandicaulis:3.10529):0.272207,(Rubus_miscix:2.288585,Rubus_spectatus:2.288585):1.088911):0.685377,(Rubus_ithacanus:3.983737,Rubus_steelei:3.983737):0.079136):0.015284,Rubus_enslenii:4.078157):0.068184,Rubus_pensilvanicus:4.146341):0.314926,(Rubus_argutus:0.58418,Rubus_cuneifolius:0.58418):3.877087):0.02081,(((Rubus_regionalis:4.019817,Rubus_canadensis:4.019817):0.059086,Rubus_rosa:4.078903):0.160428,Rubus_recurvans:4.239331):0.242746):0.015005,(Rubus_allegheniensis:4.31499,Rubus_uvidus:4.31499):0.182092):0.019612,Rubus_vermontanus:4.516694):0.891371,(Rubus_hispidus:4.440803,Rubus_permixtus:4.440803):0.967262):1.32483,Rubus_vagus:6.732895):0.023439,Rubus_superioris:6.756333):0.020104,(((((((Rubus_trivialis:1.652243,Rubus_flagellaris:1.652243):0.36229,(Rubus_multifer:0.538518,Rubus_curtipes:0.538518):1.476014):0.807236,Rubus_stipulatus:2.821768):0.295305,Rubus_junceus:3.117074):0.198123,Rubus_missouricus:3.315197):0.971918,Rubus_elegantulus:4.287115):2.388002,Rubus_alumnus:6.675117):0.101321):0.025475,((Rubus_laciniatus:0.125186,Rubus_bifrons:0.125186):0.11903,Rubus_praecox:0.244216):6.557697):4.346196,Rubus_pubescens:11.148109):0.061953,Rubus_idaeus:11.210062):0.042458,((Rubus_phoenicolasius:11.083887,Rubus_occidentalis:11.083887):0.087068,Rubus_arcticus:11.170956):0.081565):7.121242,((Rubus_uniformis:8.388795,Rubus_parviflorus:8.388795):6.470355,Rubus_odoratus:14.85915):3.514612):14.711986,Rubus_meracus:33.085749):12.992732):16.915234,((Filipendula_rubra:19.826137,Filipendula_vulgaris:19.826137):0.073841,Filipendula_ulmaria:19.899978):43.093736):13.354116,(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((Crataegus_dodgei:0.015733,Crataegus_dissona:0.015733):0.010796,Crataegus_michauxii:0.026529):0.010633,Crataegus_formosa:0.037162):0.011471,Crataegus_pedicellata:0.048633):0.014098,Crataegus_irrasa:0.062731):0.019132,Crataegus_florifera:0.081863):0.032863,Crataegus_lumaria:0.114726):0.465517,Crataegus_fulleriana:0.580243):0.006081,Crataegus_disperma:0.586324):0.099168,(Crataegus_jesupii:0.549784,Crataegus_lucorum:0.549784):0.135708):0.00584,Crataegus_fluviatilis:0.691331):0.380201,Crataegus_scabrida:1.071532):0.019968,Crataegus_calpodendron:1.0915):0.033869,Crataegus_succulenta:1.125369):0.262341,((Crataegus_holmesiana:0.712472,Crataegus_mollis:0.712472):0.144634,Crataegus_coccinioides:0.857106):0.530604):0.398534,Crataegus_marshallii:1.786245):0.228259,Crataegus_crus-galli:2.014503):0.161619,Crataegus_intricata:2.176122):0.016118,((Crataegus_macrosperma:0.790887,Crataegus_pruinosa:0.790887):0.122301,(Crataegus_chrysocarpa:0.193226,Crataegus_macracantha:0.193226):0.719962):1.279051):0.017649,Crataegus_submollis:2.209889):0.014998,Crataegus_phaenopyrum:2.224886):0.018512,Crataegus_uniflora:2.243399):0.438351,Crataegus_persimilis:2.68175):0.045017,Crataegus_punctata:2.726768):0.058153,Crataegus_laevigata:2.78492):0.065678,Crataegus_spathulata:2.850598):0.26874,Crataegus_viridis:3.119338):0.332928,Crataegus_douglasii:3.452267):0.094595,Crataegus_monogyna:3.546862):3.832148,((((((Malus_toringo:2.491744,Malus_pumila:2.491744):1.007309,Malus_baccata:3.499053):1.351718,Malus_coronaria:4.850771):1.621923,(Malus_angustifolia:0.049008,Malus_ioensis:0.049008):6.423685):0.035427,Cotoneaster_divaricatus:6.50812):0.736585,Chaenomeles_speciosa:7.244705):0.134305):1.72489,((Aronia_arbutifolia:0.094396,Aronia_melanocarpa:0.094396):8.89729,(Pyrus_communis:7.94625,Sorbus_aucuparia:7.94625):1.045436):0.112214):0.313393,((((Amelanchier_spicata:5.295684,Amelanchier_sanguinea:5.295684):0.053588,Amelanchier_alnifolia:5.349272):2.667629,((Amelanchier_arborea:0.249044,Amelanchier_bartramiana:0.249044):0.767662,Amelanchier_canadensis:1.016706):7.000194):0.24348,(Amelanchier_interior:7.807145,Amelanchier_laevis:7.807145):0.453236):1.156912):0.239145,Sorbus_decora:9.656438):1.019952,Sorbus_americana:10.67639):38.78046,((((((((((((Prunus_hortulana:3.586661,Prunus_persica:3.586661):0.523019,Prunus_mexicana:4.10968):0.275607,Prunus_munsoniana:4.385286):0.329537,(Prunus_armeniaca:1.156849,Prunus_tomentosa:1.156849):3.557974):0.032697,(Prunus_angustifolia:4.478999,Prunus_pumila:4.478999):0.268521):0.03745,Prunus_alleghaniensis:4.784971):1.404974,(Prunus_americana:2.365429,Prunus_nigra:2.365429):3.824516):0.37487,(Prunus_cerasus:2.734566,Prunus_pensylvanica:2.734566):3.830249):4.856241,((Prunus_padus:1.415647,Prunus_virginiana:1.415647):3.401352,Prunus_serotina:4.817):6.604057):29.162527,Sorbaria_sorbifolia:40.583584):2.924475,(Rhodotypos_scandens:36.33611,Physocarpus_opulifolius:36.33611):7.17195):2.718224,(((Spiraea_X_bumalda:10.834237,Spiraea_alba:10.834237):3.799914,Spiraea_tomentosa:14.634152):11.287431,Aruncus_dioicus:25.921583):20.304701):3.230567):26.89098);"
```

Note: it works on macOS R app, but not on terminal R or RStudio.

Can anyone run the above code? I am surprised that this does not work. There must be something basic about R that I am not know, even after using it for year...

Thanks!

```
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.3    assertthat_0.2.1  cli_1.1.0         tools_3.5.3       withr_2.1.2       rstudioapi_0.9.0 
[7] crayon_1.3.4      packrat_0.5.0     sessioninfo_1.1.1
```

Comment: it works for me though

Comment: @akrun thanks! That is interesting. What is your OS?

Comment: I am using `MacOS` as well - High Sierra

Comment: That's funny. The code also failed when I run on Ubuntu R3.5.0...

Comment: do you get an error? I run MacOs Mojave and if I paste that code the console expects some other inputs (`+`)

Comment: Might it be related to a maximum string length limit? https://community.rstudio.com/t/does-console-impose-an-upper-limit-on-the-length-of-strings/12872

Comment: @davide this is exactly what happened to me too! I don't understand why...

Comment: please refer to the @jsta 's link, it provides you the answer

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker It seems this is the problem!

Comment: @jsta Thanks!  This seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain why it works differently in different console environments, and particularly why it *does* work in the MacOS R application (for me it doesn't work under an ESS shell in Ubuntu), but the [link given above](https://community.rstudio.com/t/does-console-impose-an-upper-limit-on-the-length-of-strings/12872) points to a comment in the  [Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#R-commands_003b-case-sensitivity-etc):

> Command lines entered at the console are limited^4 to about 4095 bytes (not characters)

If you put the code above in a file and `source()` it, it works fine. `nchar(tree)` is 6936.

The discussion in the link also points to [the place where the limit is hardcoded in R](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/496adb0085703362b2dee63537f0d89820f5afbb/src/include/Defn.h#L1040-L1042), so if you were really desperate you could modify that value and recompile R ...